# Delaying video overlay in ffmpeg without frame drops

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding, filter

I'm trying to play 2 videos overlaid against a static background, with the 2nd video (and its audio) delayed by a couple seconds.  When I do this, ffmpeg complains about buffer overflow and the 2nd video drops tons of frames.  How do I prevent the frame drops?

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i ~/Desktop/FP2.tiff -i ~/Desktop/fp.mov -itsoffset 2 -i ~/Desktop/fp.mov -lavfi \
"[0:v]fps=60[bg]; \
[bg][1:v]overlay=10:(main_h/2)-(overlay_h/2):format=rgb[v1]; \
[v1][2:v]overlay=460:(main_h/2)-(overlay_h/2):shortest=1:format=rgb[final]; \
[2:a]adelay=2000[a2]; \
[1:a][a2]amix=inputs=2[audio]" \
-map "[final]" -map [audio] -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -c:a pcm_s16be ~/Desktop/filtergraph.nut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i ~/Desktop/FP2.tiff -i ~/Desktop/fp.mov -i ~/Desktop/fp.mov \
       -lavfi "[0][1:v]overlay=10:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:format=rgb:shortest=1[v1]; \
               [2:v]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)+2/TB[2v]; \
               [v1][2v]overlay=460:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1:format=rgb[final]; \
               [2:a]adelay=2000|2000[a2];[1:a][a2]amix=inputs=2[audio]" \
 -map "[final]" -map [audio] -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -c:a pcm_s16be ~/Desktop/filtergraph.nut
```

If this still drops frames, then you should insert a FIFO filter for the 2nd video after the setpts, like this:

```
[2:v]setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)+2/TB,fifo[2v]
```

Comment: That one works.  The "fifo" is needed.  I was able to trim the fat on the command as well and get rid of the 2nd reference to the same video input altogether as well.

Thanks for the help!